# Content-type and @ResponseBody in spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-restcontroller

It could be very simple but it will be very helpful for me to understand...

I used @ResponseBody in my restcontroller to return String value to browser. The response string is successfully received in browser.

ie:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/foo", method=RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public String foo() {
    return "bar";
}
```

What is the content-type of above response? If this is going to be like writing setAttribute in servlet response what could the attribute name?

If the browser accept only "application/json" how spring will treat the response?

Comment: did you try produces="text/plain"..  it can be helpful .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Submitted code produces text/html, as do all mapped Controller methods by default. If you want to produce application/json, you have to change your RequestMapping to

```
@RequestMapping(value="/foo", method=RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/json")
```

However this is not a valid Json String, you would have to change it because the method you submitted would return empty body. The submitted example would be valid text/plain.

When the request contains header `"Accept: application/json"` and other content type is returned, Spring returns Json-type response explaining that `HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException` was thrown.

Regarding the servlet analogy - please explain, I don't fully understand what you mean. The String is returned as response body, it's very different from request attributes. What would you like to achieve?

Answer (score 3):

I assume the content type will be plain/text. If the request sets accept to "application/json" it depends on your browser/tool. Most rest clients won't display it as it is not application/json. If you invoke the API directly I would assume it is displayed due to browser content sniffing (can be disabled via a header).

Comment: Thanks for answering. One more clarification is, Writting in response body means setting key/value pair in the response.. (something like setting attribute in the response)

Comment: You could either create a JSONObject and use the toString(), use a mapper framework like jackson or you create a string like "{\"key\":\"value\"}"